# MFC - How can I disable a list item?

Tags: mfc, clistctrl

I have a CListCtrl with checkboxes. I want to be able to disable one of the items so that the user cannot click the checkbox. Is this possible? If so, how?

**Edit:**
Found the specifics on how to hide a checkbox in another question
[Need only some rows in a CListCtrl control to have check boxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190667)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shortly: Not easily possible.

You'll need to sub-class the `CListCtrl` and implement this behavior on your own or download for example the [MFC Grid Control](http://www.codeguru.com/Cpp/controls/controls/gridcontrol/article.php/c2179) that allows you to do that.

As for the removing check-boxes idea, yes, that might be possible, MSDN:

> Version 4.70. Enables check boxes for items in a list-view control. When
>   set to this style, the control creates
>   and sets a state image list with two
>   images using DrawFrameControl. State
>   image 1 is the unchecked box, and
>   state image 2 is the checked box.
>   **Setting the state image to zero**
>   **removes the check box.**